# Authorizing SignUp Page to anyone with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security

If I use a token I can access the user page fine http://localhost:8901/auth/user.

but if I try to get only the signup/registration "api call" supposed to be accessible by anyone I get :
"Full authentication is required to access this resource".

I tried the following

```
 httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/registration")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
```

then tried to see if I could enable everything but would still get the same error:

```
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
```

Some of the classes I have

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("{noop}password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password("{noop}password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

application.yml file

```
#Setting the logging levels for the service
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    com.test: DEBUG

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

server:
  port: 8901
  servlet:
    context-path: /auth
```

bootstrap.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: authenticationservice
  profiles:
    active:
      default
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        userInfo.put("authorities", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
        return userInfo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/validate"}, produces = "application/json")
    public User validate(OAuth2Authentication user)
    {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(user.getName());
    }

  
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void register(@RequestBody UserRegistrationDetails userRegDetails) {
        logger.debug("Entering the register method");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(userRegDetails.getUserName()) || EmailValidator.emailValidator(userRegDetails.getUserName()) == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidException("Invalid email provided");
        }
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByUserName(userRegDetails.getUserName());
        if (existingUser != null)
            throw new InvalidException("The User already exists");
        if (EmailValidator.emailValidator(userRegDetails.getPassword()))
            throw new InvalidException("The provided password is invalid");
        User user = User.UserBuilder
                .builder()
                .withEnabled(true)
                .withUserName(userRegDetails.getUserName()).withPassword(userRegDetails.getPassword())
                .withEnabled(false)
                .withAuthorizationCode("SOMECODE")
                .withApplicationId(userRegDetails.getApplicationId())
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

Edit, adding OAuth2Config

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseUserRegistrationDetailsService userRegistrationDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("test")
                .secret("{noop}somesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
      endpoints
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userRegistrationDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call seems to trigger the Resource-Server parts of the code. That is expecting a token for authorization. Configure the exception like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registration")
            .permitAll();
  }
}
```

You can remove the @EnableResourceServer from the main class.

Comment: Thanks a lot I thought that EnableResourceServer needed to be set along with @SpringBootApplication, I removed the configure(HttpSecurity http) from the WebSecurityConfigurer and used the ResourceServerConfig you proposed instead. Everything looks fine now so I marked your answer as correct!