# Spring Boot OAuth2 login endpoint not working. Getting 404 when hitting default path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to implement OAuth2 in my Spring Boot App.

I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Basic config for GitHub (for example):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: xxx
            client-secret: xxx
```

And basic WebSecurity config allowing all endpoints:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

When client-id/secret is not provided, an exception occurs so the config is picked up properly.

But I can't access the oauth login page which should be http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/github, I have an 404 instead.

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066896/authorizing-signup-page-to-anyone-with-websecurityconfigureradapter/65075623#65075623) might help you.